# Раскрывающееся меню

Tags: javascript

**UPDATE!!!**

Нужно если внутри li есть элемент с классом sub-menu - то ссылка внутри li не кликобильная, а все остальные кликобильные + желательно, чтобы по клику на ссылки во внутреннем меню оно не сворачивалось. http://ssmaker.ru/749161e2.png

http://jsfiddle.net/wpkta7r1/1/

Огромное спасибо всем, кто поможет!

Answer (score 1):

Ответ на первый вопрос:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var parentLi = $('.left_menu > li'), insertUl = $('.left_menu > li > ul');

    parentLi.click(function(e) {
        // кликнули по ссылке, являющейся непосредственным потомком parentLi
        var is_clicked_first_level_link = $(e.target).closest('li').is($(this));
        // кликнули по parentLi, у которого есть вложенное .sub-menu
        var has_sub_menu = $(this).has('ul').length;
        if (has_sub_menu && is_clicked_first_level_link) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).find(insertUl).slideToggle();
        }
    });
});
```

Соберите пример на **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)**, демонстрирующий проблему, тогда смогу вам помочь и со вторым вопросом.

Comment: Вот: jsfiddle.net/wpkta7r1

Comment: @rodion, все работает. Первый ответ исправил и вторую проблему. Вот ваш же пример: `http://jsfiddle.net/wpkta7r1/1/`

Comment: @VenZell , так нужно, чтобы ссылка не работала только там, где меню (class="sub-menu")

Comment: @rodion, вот вам обновленный пример: `http://jsfiddle.net/wpkta7r1/9/`

Answer (score 0):

На первый вопрос уже ответили.
Во втором проблемы нет.
[Вот доказательство](http://jsfiddle.net/3mjmhkct/)

Comment: @sepgg, не совсем ответили (я описал ситуацию чуть выше).